# ARIMA - Regressor Effects

Tags: r, forecasting, arima

I am new to R and forecasting. I have access to weekly data (104 weeks) for a certain SKU, its value and volume sales and a few promo variables.

Promo 1 and Promo 2 are continuous variables (unfortunately Promo 1 is 0 here for this SKU) while Promo 3 and Promo 4 are categorical variables.

I tried forecasting the volume sales for this SKU for the next 72 weeks. I included dummy variables using `seasonaldummy` function

```
actual_vol = ts(data$Volume , frequency =52)
dummy = seasonaldummy(actual_vol)
xreg = cbind(data$Promo1 , data$Promo2 , data$Promo3 , data$Promo4 , dummy)

fit = auto.arima(actual_vol , xreg = xreg)
```

I am trying to forecast sales for the next 72 weeks by keeping my promo variables as 0 (basically baseline sales). I used `seasonaldummyf` and promo variables as 0 for forecast.

The plot looks something like this
[image: Forecast - Arima]

As you can see the forecast looks exactly the same as the previous data (same as using `snaive`) and it seems promo had no effect at all on volume sales.

Kindly let me know if the method is correct and if not how can I improve it.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6sOv1da0JMeVHl1SlRMZmJDODQ/view?usp=sharing

Comment: What are you expecting the forecasting(software) method to do? If you have prior beliefs you need to incorporate them.

Comment: You may also consider including seasonal effects via dummies due to Easter and/or other events that could be relevant to the sales of a particular SKU and that do not occur on the same date every year. Also, using 52 weeks per year is fine in the short run, but over a few years the extra day or two at the end of each year will accumulate and make your forecasts less accurate; see e.g. [this](http://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/seasonal-periods/) (and also [this](http://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/longseasonality/)) post in Rob J. Hyndman's blog.

Comment: thanks a lot Richard .I shall incorporate these in my model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took your data and used AUTOBOX ( a commercially available piece of software that I have helped develop ) to automatically analyze your data. AUTOBOX found that one of your promotional variables (PROMO2) was statistically significant.[image] . A plot of the Actual/Fit and Forecast is of interest as it shows the dynamic buildup/change starting at week 35 of each year lasting some 21 weeks.[image] . The plot of the forecasts is here [image] with values here [image] . Your solution was flawed by ignoring the 6 points in time that were "unusual" and by using seasonal arima structure rather than specific week of-the-year effects . Anomalies have a deleterious effect on parameter estimation thus they need to be treated thus any parameters that are estimated without adjusting for outliers are not robust e.g. your ar coefficient.